# How to append to system path programmatically?

Tags: python, python-2.7, path

In python how can I programmatically append to my system path? I'm aware of `sys.path.append` and just searched the docs, I'm a little confused though. It tells me that `sys.path.append` only appends to the `PYTHONPATH` and not the actual system path. Is there a way I can programmatically append to the system path temporarily?

Answer (score 3):

Just update the environment `PATH` variable:

```
old_path = os.environ['PATH']
try:
    os.environ['PATH'] = "{}{}{}".format('/my/new/path', os.pathsep, old_path)
finally:
    os.environ['PATH'] = old_path
```

Alternately, its common for programs to keep a separate environment they use when calling other tools.

```
env = os.environ.copy()
env['PATH'] = "{}{}{}".format('/my/new/path', os.pathsep, env['PATH'])
# change other env here...
subprocess.check_call(['my', 'tool'], env=env)
```

Comment: That works perfectly, so am I correct that `sys.append.path` only does the `PYTHONPATH` itself?

Comment: @Pyth0nicPenguin First of all it is [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path)(`.append`) and yes only `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: @Pyth0nicPenguin - Not quite. `sys.path.append` appends to the module lookup path for the running program only. If it executes other programs, they will only see the `PYTHONPATH` from the original environment. - And I mean execute as a child process, not import. If you execute other python scripts and want them to see a different path, you need to play the same `os.environ` game with `PYTHONPATH`.